# Why is my collision count so high? (C++ hashtable)

Tags: c++, hashtable, collision

I'm doing an assignment with hash tables. The hash table functions were already made, we just had to implement a hash table rehashing size count, a load factor calculation, a collision counter, and a spellcheck. Everything is done except for the collision counter, which for some reason is way higher than I'm supposed to be getting. (We have an expected output of 42802, I'm getting 55535). The only thing I can think of is the hash table uses lazy deletion so maybe I'm not accounting for that properly? I'm not sure. Here's the header and cpp files, respectively.

```
#ifndef QUADRATIC_PROBING_CPP
#define QUADRATIC_PROBING_CPP

#include <iostream>
#include "QuadraticProbing.h"
using namespace std;


template <class HashedObj>
HashTable<HashedObj>::HashTable( int size )
  : array( nextPrime( size ) )
{
  makeEmpty();
}

template <class HashedObj>
void HashTable<HashedObj>::makeEmpty( )
{
  
  currentSize = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i < array.size( ); i++ )
    {
      array[ i ].info = EMPTY;
    }
}

template<class HashedObj>
double HashTable<HashedObj>::loadFactor() const{
  return static_cast<double>(currentSize) / array.size();
}

template <class HashedObj>
bool HashTable<HashedObj>::isPrime( int n )
{
    if( n == 2 || n == 3 )
        return true;

    if( n == 1 || n % 2 == 0 )
        return false;

    for( int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2 )
        if( n % i == 0 )
            return false;

    return true;
}

template <class HashedObj>
int HashTable<HashedObj>::nextPrime( int n )
{
    if( n % 2 == 0 )
        n++;

    for( ; !isPrime( n ); n += 2 )
        ;

    return n;
}


template <class HashedObj>
bool HashTable<HashedObj>::contains( const HashedObj & x ) const
{
  return isActive( findPos( x ) );
}


template <class HashedObj>
bool HashTable<HashedObj>::insert( const HashedObj & x, int &rehashCounter, int &sizeIncrease, int &collisionCount)
{
  
  // Insert x as active
  int currentPos = findPos( x );
  if( isActive( currentPos ) )
    return false;
  
  array[ currentPos ].element = x;
  array[ currentPos ].info = ACTIVE;

  // Rehash
  if( ++currentSize > array.size( ) / 2 ){
    
    int oldSize = array.size();
    vector<HashEntry> oldArray = array;
    rehash(rehashCounter, sizeIncrease, collisionCount);
    int newSize = array.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++){
    int newPos = findPos(oldArray[i].element);
    if (oldArray[i].info == ACTIVE && newPos != currentPos) {
        // Check if the element from the old array collided with a different element
        collisionCount++;
    }
  }
    sizeIncrease += newSize - oldSize;
    cout << "Rehashing. New size is " << sizeIncrease << endl;
  }

  return true;
}

template <class HashedObj>
bool HashTable<HashedObj>::remove( const HashedObj & x )
{
  int currentPos = findPos( x );
  if( !isActive( currentPos ) )
    return false;
  
  array[ currentPos ].info = DELETED;
  return true;
}


template <class HashedObj>
bool HashTable<HashedObj>::isActive( int currentPos ) const
{
  return array[ currentPos ].info == ACTIVE;
}

template <class HashedObj>
int HashTable<HashedObj>::findPos( const HashedObj & x ) const
{
  int offset = 1;
  int currentPos = myhash( x );

  while( array[ currentPos ].info != EMPTY &&
     array[ currentPos ].element != x )
    {
      currentPos += offset;  // Compute ith probe
      offset += 2;
      if( currentPos >= array.size( ) )
    currentPos -= array.size( );
    }

  return currentPos;
}

template <class HashedObj>
void HashTable<HashedObj>::rehash(int &counter, int &sizeIncrease, int &collisionCount)
{
  
  vector<HashEntry> oldArray = array;
  int oldSize = array.size();

  // Create new double-sized, empty table
  array.resize( nextPrime( 2 * oldArray.size( ) ) );
  for( int j = 0; j < array.size( ); j++ )
    array[ j ].info = EMPTY;
  
  
  // Copy table over
  currentSize = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i < oldArray.size( ); i++ )
    if( oldArray[ i ].info == ACTIVE )
      insert(oldArray[ i ].element, counter, sizeIncrease, collisionCount);
}



template <class HashedObj>
int HashTable<HashedObj>::myhash( const HashedObj & x ) const
{
  int hashVal= hashKey(x); 
  
  hashVal %= array.size( );
  if( hashVal < 0 )
    hashVal += array.size( );
  
  return hashVal;
}

template <class HashedObj>
int HashTable<HashedObj>::hashKey( int key) const
{
  return key;
}

template <class HashedObj>
int HashTable<HashedObj>::hashKey(const string & key) const
{
  int hashVal = 0;

  for( int i = 0; i < key.length( ); i++ )
    hashVal = 37 * hashVal + key[ i ];
  
  return hashVal;
  
}


#endif
```

```
#ifndef QUADRATIC_PROBING_H
#define QUADRATIC_PROBING_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



enum EntryType { ACTIVE, EMPTY, DELETED };

// QuadraticProbing Hash table class
//
// CONSTRUCTION: an approximate initial size or default of 101
//
// ******************PUBLIC OPERATIONS*********************
// bool insert( x )       --> Insert x
// bool remove( x )       --> Remove x
// bool contains( x )     --> Return true if x is present
// void makeEmpty( )      --> Remove all items
// int hash( string str ) --> Global method to hash strings

template <class HashedObj>
class HashTable
{
public:

  //constuctor, default size: 101
  HashTable(int size = 101);

  //Return true if x is present
  bool contains( const HashedObj & x ) const;

  //Remove all items from the hash table
  void makeEmpty( );
    
  //insert x
  bool insert( const HashedObj & x, int &rehashCounter, int &sizeIncrease, int &collisionCount);

  //remove x
  bool remove( const HashedObj & x );

  double loadFactor() const;

  
private:
  //hash table entry
  struct HashEntry
  {
    HashedObj element;
    EntryType info;
  };


  //hash table
  vector<HashEntry> array;

  //size of the hash table
  int currentSize;

  int collisionCount;

  //check to see if the given position is active
  bool isActive( int currentPos ) const;

  //find the position of given x
  int findPos( const HashedObj & x ) const;

  //rehash
  void rehash(int &counter, int &sizeIncrease, int &collisionCount);

  //return the hash table index of x
  int myhash( const HashedObj & x ) const;

  //find the next prime greater than n
  int nextPrime( int n );

  //check if n is prime
  bool isPrime( int n );

  //compute the hash key when x is integer
  int hashKey(int key) const;

  //compute the hash key when x is a string
  int hashKey(const string & key) const;

  
};

#include "QuadraticProbing.cpp"

#endif
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "QuadraticProbing.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Simple main
int main( )
{
  std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
  int rehashCount = 0;
  int sizeIncrease = 101;
  int collisionCount = 0;
  int wordLength;
  string word, wordOriginal;
  bool check1 = false;
  bool check2 = false;
  bool check3 = false;
  vector<string> s;
  HashTable<string> table3;
  char alpha[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
  string myText;
  char c = 0;

  cout << "Insert words\n";
  std::ifstream myReadFile("words.dat");
  while(std::getline(myReadFile, myText)){
    table3.insert(myText, rehashCount, sizeIncrease, collisionCount);
  }

  cout << "\nThe load factor is " << table3.loadFactor() << "." << endl;
  cout << "Collision count: " << collisionCount << endl;

  
  
  for (char &c : word) { //Convert to lowercase for search
    c = tolower(c);
  }

  while(true){

  s.clear();

  cout << "\nEnter a word for spell checking (enter done to exit):  ";
  cin >> word;

  if(word.find("done") != std::string::npos){
    break;
  }
  
  if(table3.contains(word))
  {
    cout << "Correct! " << endl;
    break;
  }
    //logic when word not found, and word is just missing character
    wordLength = word.length();

    wordOriginal = word;
    for(int j = 0; j < 25; j++){

      word = wordOriginal;

      word.insert(0, 1, alpha[j]);

      for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){

        c = word[i];
        word[i] = word[i + 1];
        word[i + 1]= c;
        if(table3.contains(word)){
          s.push_back(word);
          break;
        } 
      }
  }
  
    //logic for when word not found, and word has extra character
    word = wordOriginal;
    for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){
      word = word.erase(i, 1);
      if(table3.contains(word)){
        s.push_back(word);
        
      }
      word = wordOriginal;
      
    }
  
  
    word = wordOriginal;
    int counter = 0;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){
    word = wordOriginal;
    
    for(int j=0; j < 25; j++){
      word = word.replace(i, 1, 1, alpha[j]);
      if(table3.contains(word)){
        
        s.push_back(word);
        
      }
    }
  }
  cout << "Suggestions: \n";
  for (const auto& element : s){
    cout << element << " ";
  }

  

  }
  cout << "Bye. ";
  
}
```

Comment: Side note: Don't inflict pain (so much pain!) on yourself with `#include "QuadraticProbing.cpp"`. Too many tools (and humans) helpfully recognize a cpp file as a source file to be compiled. So they compile it. And then the linker doesn't know what so do when it finds the included copies and the original. You dodge this problem by having no definitions in the cpp file, but that's a mere one refactoring away from failure. Instead give the .cpp file any other extension, .hpp, for example..

Comment: Side note: QuadraticProbing.h includes QuadraticProbing.cpp. QuadraticProbing..cpp includes QuadraticProbing.h. This circular reference is another potential failure point.

Comment: Recommendation: make a small input set that produces an incorrect count, then step through the program and see where and how the count goes wrong. Use what you learn to isolate the mistake and then crush it. If you're still stuck, you're only a few steps away from being able to post a [mre] (MRE), and help me debug question without a MRE are generally poorly received.

Comment: Instead of `.cpp` as the extension of the template implementation file, I've seen projects use `.ipp` or `.tpp`, and have those `#include`d at the end of the header file.  (But mostly, the template implementations are right in the header file itself.)

Comment: Side note: I see member variable `int collisionCount;` and `int &collisionCount` in `rehash` and `insert`. Since you call `rehash` and `rehash` with the member `collisionCount` as parameter `collisionCount`, you avoid most of the pain that comes from reusing the identifier--accidentally changing the wrong variable because the parameter shadows the member--but the result is a pointless abstraction. Get rid of the parameter.

Comment: The headers were already pre-made by the professor, but good to know regardless.

Comment: Disappointing. Professors should know better.

Comment: Note: collisions are counted on insert and again during rehash. One item in the table could be counted many times because of this. This might be the reason why the professor has `int &collisionCount` parameters. They could expect you to be recomputing from 0 the number of collisions when the program rehashes rather than maintaining a running total of all collisions.

Comment: How does the professor expect the collisions to be counted? Did they specify it in the assignment?

Comment: The only hint I have is that it says "There are in total 42802 collisions during initialization." in the expected results file.

Comment: Huh. Now that I'm really looking at it, where is the member `int collisionCount;` initialized? If you don't set it to zero you can't count on it starting at zero. Change `HashTable<HashedObj>::HashTable( int size )
  : array( nextPrime( size ) )` to `HashTable<HashedObj>::HashTable( int size )
  : array( nextPrime( size ) ), collisionCount(0)` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: It *should* be set to 0, it is set to zero in the test.cpp function and is then passed into the insert when making the table.

Comment: What happens outside the class stays outside the class. Whatever test.cpp set to zero is another variable that has no connection to the member `collisionCount`. Because the `collisionCount` parameter is being used everywhere, it's possible that the member `collisionCount`  has absolutely no purpose.

Comment: Can you add the test.cpp file's contents to the question so that we may experiment?

Comment: Edited. Also that change didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @imnapr As mentioned already, reduce the size of the data to something that you can track easily.  Collision counts into the multiple thousands is virtually impossible to debug, unless you know exactly where in the code the issue is, and so far, it looks like you don't know.  Thus reduce the sample size to something manageable.  `std::ifstream myReadFile("words.dat");` -- That file should contain 10 words, and maybe even not that many, to figure out the problem.  If that file contains hundreds or thousands of words, well, if it doesn't work with 10 words, it isn't going to work with thousands.

Comment: The uninitialized `collisionCount member variable has no effect on the program. It's never used. Wasted space and wasted time investigating it.

Comment: Paul's right, but to really give the thing a workout with a ten-string dictionary you'd want to set the starting size to 2 so you can get a few resizes in. Sadly because the input isn't built into `main`, we cannot help you get exactly the right number of collisions and prove it. We can't prove whatever changes we make provide the same count that the professor gets. For all we know, their number's wrong  as well.

Comment: Side note: `hashKey` can overflow an `int` and result in Undefined Behaviour and an unstable program, In real life, use an unsigned integer here. A) unsigned overflow is well defined and B) you never get a negative number. A negative number as an array index is almost always a terrible idea.

Comment: I'll try emailing my professor tomorrow morning to see if I can't get some pointers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Side note: Brute force prime computation is sssssslllllloooooooowwwwwww. In real life you'd use a sieve to produce all of the prime numbers you can get and store them in a table. When you need a prime, you get it out of the table rather than doing the same work over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: I was counting in the wrong place. Adding `collisionCount` inside the `while` loop of the `findPos` function gave the right count.

```
template <class HashedObj>
int HashTable<HashedObj>::findPos( const HashedObj & x ) const
{
  int offset = 1;
  int currentPos = myhash( x );

  while( array[ currentPos ].info != EMPTY &&
     array[ currentPos ].element != x )
    {
      currentPos += offset;  // Compute ith probe
      offset += 2;
      collisionCount++;
      if( currentPos >= array.size( ) ){
        currentPos -= array.size( );
      }
    }
  
  return currentPos;
}
```